# iOS TableViewCell Hide/Unhide multiple cells when clicking on one cell with objective C

Tags: ios, uitableview, height, show-hide

I have a tableView that has 8 cells. When you click cell 2 I want to hide/unhide cells 3-5.But I don't know how to send those cell number to the height or am I messing. I also need to know how to refresh the menu after the height is change. Thanks in advance.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if([indexPath row] == 1){
        '';//

    }else if([indexPath row] == 2){

         if( viewCells ==0){
             viewCells =1;
             //  What needs to be here to change the 3-5 index height
         }else{
             viewCells =0;
             //  What needs to be here to change the 3-5 index height
         }
    }else if([indexPath row] == 3){

        //
    }else if([indexPath row] == 4){

        //
    }else if([indexPath row] == 5){

        //
    }else if([indexPath row] == 6){

        //
    }else if([indexPath row] == 7){

        //
    }else if([indexPath row] == 8){
        //
    }
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if(viewCells==0){

        return 44;
    }else{

        return 0;
    }
    return 44;
}
```

Comment: select your code and hit control+k . It will format it properly.This is nothing related to question.

Answer (score 0):

With some help from a friend I got it to work. Here is the code.

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

  KYDrawerController *menu = (KYDrawerController*)self.parentViewController;
  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
  if([indexPath row] == 1) {
      //
  }else if([indexPath row] == 2) {
      _advanced = !_advanced;
      [[self tableView] reloadData];
      return;
  }else if(_advanced){
      if([indexPath row] == 3) {
          //
      }else if([indexPath row] == 4){
          //
      }else if([indexPath row] == 5){
          //
      }else if([indexPath row] == 6){
          //
      }else if([indexPath row] == 7){
          //
      }else if([indexPath row] == 8){
          //
      }
  }else{
      if([indexPath row] == 3){
          //
      }else if([indexPath row] == 4){
          //
      }
  }
  [menu setDrawerState:KYDrawerControllerDrawerStateClosed animated:YES];
  [menu reloadInputViews];
  }
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
  if(!_advanced && indexPath.row > 2){
      indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 4 inSection:indexPath.section];
  }
  return [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  }
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
  if(!_advanced)
      return [super tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] - 4;
  return [super tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
  }